# Reassemble sniffed packets

Tags: network, wifi, sniffer, packet

I am attempting to analyse my WiFi network with on Mac OS X, is there a tool to reassemble TCP stream from Wireshark capture. I would like to see the entire HTML pages that are passing through the WiFi

Comment: I use [`justniffer_grab_http_traffic`](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/#!/justniffer_grab_http_traffic). Very easy and straightforward.

Comment: For HTTP you can use httpry which is based on libpcap as well, but only focuses on HTTP traffic.

Comment: @Adnan thank you but it is not mac compatible...

Comment: @Newben It is. Just download the source and compile it. If you want something that is compiled and ready for Mac OS X, you can use [Bro](http://www.bro.org/download/index.html).

Comment: This isn't really a security question - it is simply requesting info on how to use a networking tool. Best answered by looking at the large amount of online documentation and walkthroughs for wireshark.

Comment: Additionally, it seems the majority of your questions here are getting closed as off-topic. I would suggest revisiting not only our faq, but that on Stack Overflow for guidance. Generally if it is a config question, or usage of a network tool etc, it will be off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just right click on any HTTP packet and select "Follow TCP Stream" which will rebuild the page. You could select the "Save As" and save it somewhere, e.g.: "captured-page.html"

Edited to add more:

Here is the walk through on Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html Your other option is to use [tcpflow](http://alternativeto.net/software/tcpflow/?platform=mac): tcpflow -r http.cap

Comment: thank you, but when I right click on any packet, nothing happens. Btw, the captured-page.html appears in an non readable ascii format

Comment: thank you very much, but the problem is that when I open the caputured-page.html, I get some non readable text with raw caracters...